# What do we call this type of discourse?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Someone, guilty of a wrongdoing, defends his position by reminding the accusing party that, at some point in time, s/he was guilty of the same wrongdoing too. This is instead of making an apology or a promise to change behavior in the future. What do we call such a discourse?

> **Speaker A:** You treated the audience with disrespect (The guilty part does not deny the accusation)
>
> **Speaker B:** Yes I did, but did you never do the same thing? (Suggesting that Speaker A isn't in a position to make accusations)

Now, I have considered using many phrases and expressions like "fault-finding," "blame game," "finger pointing," "cherry-picking," and "apologetics." While they are 'close' to what I want to say, they all roughly connote an act of defense by denying guilt and laying it on someone else (usually the accuser), as in **"You did it, not me!"** What I am looking for, however, is a word/phrase suggesting that the accused party indeed admits guilt, but tries to ameliorate his position by saying something like **"Hey, but I am not the only one. You did it too."**

Comment: Is it *reproach* you're looking for?

Comment: @Sander: I thought of that one too. but "reproach", "admonition," and their similars still sound like "Not me, it is you!"

Comment: [Comparative Reasoning](http://changingminds.org/disciplines/argument/types_reasoning/comparison.htm) *establishes the importance of something by comparing it against something else. The size of the gap between the things compared indicates importance.* For my money, that means my transgression isn't important if you (and perhaps by implication many others) have done the same thing. Proverbially expressed as [Let him who is without sin cast the first stone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/let+him+who+is+without+sin+cast+the+first+stone).

Comment: The phrase *turnabout is fair play* is often used to justify a deliberate retaliatory act, but not as a simple excuse or deflection. Similarly *payback*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They would be committing a "*[tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque)*" logical fallacy, where they do not deny guilt, but attempt to mitigate criticism by pointing out that the accuser is also guilty.

> **Tu quoque** (/tuːˈkwoʊkwiː/; Latin for "you, too" or "you, also") or the **appeal to hypocrisy** is an informal logical fallacy that intends to discredit the validity of the opponent's logical argument by asserting the opponent's failure to act consistently in accordance with its conclusion(s).

See also [here](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/tuquoque.html) and [here](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/13-ad-hominem-tu-quoque).

Comment: @asef: I think an "Exactly!!!" with three exclamation points rather merits a check mark, don't you? Click the check mark and reward mike32 for helping you out.

Comment: @Robusto I never noticed the check mark option before, and thank you so much for pointing that out. Indeed it merits a check mark and I just checked it. Thank you Mike32.

Comment: @asef: That's why we go over this stuff. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned an "audience": in a televised debate, a common strategy is to attach negatives to one's opponent, and to offset negatives attaching to oneself by attaching the same negative (or an equally damaging one) to the opponent.

**Mudslinging** is a term used to describe this type of discourse.

Answer (score 0):

[People who live in glass houses should not throw stones.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/people+who+live+in+glass+houses+shouldn't+throw+stones)

> You should not criticize other people for having the same faults that
>   you yourself have.

In your example,

> **Speaker A**: You treated the audience with disrespect
>
> **Speaker B**: People who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones.